# usage of から at the end of the first sentence with the second part in the next

Tags: meaning

My question is on how to properly interpret utterances like the below.

> あれに正面から挑むのは中々に手間よ。どうするの？
>
> 下手な小細工が通じる相手じゃないからなあ。正面から挑むだけだよ

Occasionally I'll see someone end the sentence with からな・からね where the sentence could have continued on and still had made sense without the 。.

Should these utterances be treated like 「下手な小細工が通じる相手じゃないから正面から挑むだけだよ」 in terms of meaning but with the interjection particle there to serve its function, Should it be treated as two separate utterances with implied stuff after the から, or something else?

edit:additional examples

(rumour of the protagonists duel has spread throughout the school and his friends are talking about it.

```
「あいかわらず、噂の拡散スピードが尋常じゃないわね。デイルが口に出したの、ついさっきの授業なのに」

「まあ、ある意味で閉鎖された世界のうえに、みんな娯楽に飢えてるからな。こういった噂はいち早く広まるさ」

「それにまあ、デイルは人気あるからな。あのデイルが人族と勝負、となれば誰もが興味深々だろう
```

edit 2: After l'électeur's post I went and opened up some studies done on the usage of から and came across [原因・理由表現とは](http://hougen.sakura.ne.jp/shuppan/2007/1-1.pdf) which describes the usage of 「から」と「ので」 with 5 usages.

```
(1)事態の原因-主節が具体的な事実・事態を表し、従属節が主節の事態そのものを引き起こす原因・理
由を表す場合であ

(2)行為の理由-主節に話者の意志的な行為や聞き手に対する働きかけが現れ、その行為を行う理由が「か
 ら」「ので」によってされる。

(3)判断の根拠-This one is too long but this isn't the usage anyway

(4)発言・態度の根拠-主節に、聞き手に対する働きかけや話し手の意志などの発言や態度が現れ、そのような
 発言・態度の根拠を表す場合がある。

(5)理由を表さない用法-原因・理由文の中には、原因・理由を表しているとはいい難いものがある
```

and lastly we have the usage of it as a sentence ending particle(which in this case fits with the location)

Could anyone explain which usage this then and how it is used?

Based on my understanding of these it isn't 1 or 3.
4 and 2 I'm not really sure about but they don't seem to fit which then means it would be the usage of it as a sentence ending particle(which I haven't been able to find any real documents about that explain its usage apart from implying something else after the utterance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「あれに[正面]{しょうめん}から[挑]{いど}むのは[中々]{なかなか}に[手間]{てま}よ。どうするの？」
>
> 「[下手]{へた}な[小細工]{こざいく}が[通]{つう}じる[相手]{あいて}じゃないからなあ。正面から挑むだけだよ。」

My own translation (just in case):

> Person A: "It'll be pretty troublesome challenging that guy head-on.  What ya gonna do?"
>
> Person B: "He's not the kind to fall for cheap tricks, for sure.  Guess I'll just challenge him head-on."

***My answer*** to your question would be that the two sentences in Person B's line (in the original, of course) would look better if they were left as are in two separate sentences.

Why?  Because for the sentence structure 「Mini-sentence #1 + から + Mini-sentence #2。」 to sound natural, the content of Mini-sentence #2 would need to represent the logical and specific (or concrete) result or effect of the content of Mini-sentence #1.

In your example, the idea of 「正面から挑む」 was originally mentioned by Person A, not Person B, to begin with.  In addition, 「正面から挑む」 as a strategy is not a very specific one.  It is almost like saying "Let's go for broke!"

What would happen if you combined the two sentences into one using から in the middle?  Quite frankly, I do not think most native speakers would notice anything strange.  I noticed it because this is a place for questions and answers and I read your question carefully a few times.  Had I read the combined-into-one sentence in a story, I probably would not have felt anything really unusual about it.  It is 100% informal spoken language, so people would just read on without thinking anything.

Comment: If possible just let me ask some more things then. So in this case what is the usage of から actually doing? You mentioned that it needs to represent the logical and specific(or concrete) result or effect of sentence #1 which I can sort of grasp. For example the sentence 尽くした上で、正面攻撃でも裏面からでも効果が変わらないから、正面から挑む shows what you said. I'm not quite sure how to put it, but から it many cases serves for lack of a better term an "explanatory function".

If this is not then acting as the から which explains the reason for something then the only other real definition I can find that fits is（終助詞的に用いて）強い主張、決意を表す

Comment: Point is this is informal spoken language and dictionary definitions may not apply.  I was unable to find the usage in this particular context in my dictionaries, either.  All I know for certain is that many Japanese-speakers around me, including myself, use わけ this way all the time.  If I were to define it, I might call it "the FYI から".  You give a piece of info to another person using から at the end as a kind of prerequisite information based on which the other person may or may not take an action.  (Continued)

Comment: For instance, when I come home from somewhere, I may say to the other members of the family 「もう帰ってるから。」.  What I mean by that is if they need me to do something, I could because I am home.  It is not the "reason から".  If I come home a little late, another family member may say to me, 「もう晩ご飯食べちゃったからね。」.  That just means that they have already eaten and I could either eat my portion by myself now or do something else first and eat later on.  I would not call that a "reason から", either.  The から in your story sounds similar to this as well if not exactly the same.  (Continued)

Comment: Guy B is just presenting the information based on which A and/or B might come up with an idea, which is why I called it the ”FYI から”.

Comment: Starting from your first comment. You said わけ was used "this way all the time", did you mean that it was being used in a way that wasn't in any dictionaries(if so I've seen it lots as well so I can agree there), or did you mean it was used in the same way as this から(which I can't easily think of). From what you say this usage then corresponds to number 5 in the paper I linked. I've seen the usage before in the sentences like the above 「もう晩ご飯食べちゃったからね。」which I do understand, but the problem was trying to understand why he used から here. (Continued)

Comment: I'm not sure what the general consensus is for this as I've seen some agree and disagree but in this there is the unspoken message behind the から which the speaker believes the listener will be able to understand it without them finishing it off. Similar with けど etc in the sentences like 先生、お手洗いに行きたいんですが. (Anyway back to から for now), would you say that the usage of から in the original example had an unspoken message behind it suggesting that there wouldn't be a point in coming up with a plan to use tricks because they won't work against him, or what else would it say if you were to say it.

Answer (score 1):

Holy Cow, You are soooooooooooo good at Japanese!.

Anyway, I was interested in this discussion so that let me join in as a "complement" lol.

I would like to apologize first off if my "answer" MAY be difficult since your question level is quite high.

Now, let me go onto your first question.

> > Should these utterances be treated like 「下手な小細工が通じる相手じゃないから正面から挑むだけだよ」 in terms of meaning but with the interjection particle there to serve its function, Should it be treated as two separate utterances with implied stuff after the から, or something else?

I am afraid, your English is a bit difficult( I would appreciate if you "clarify" or rather, please do not ask in a long sentence, but cut some part one by one, so that I can comprehend precisely (s)).

After having read your sentence, I personally assumed you know very well the definition
of this particle な. な is the particle denoting the "utterance" by the person who said
it him/her self. And after checking and surfing through the multiple sites, なあ is a
variable version of な, ( and especially spoken in the "West Japan"??????? I DO use, however ) but defined same with な, but "to me, personally", なあ sounds
more frank than な. Though even な itself stands as a frank word to me.

And

> > Should it be treated as two separate utterances with implied stuff after the から, or something else?

**No.** We go here to your last question.

> > edit 2: After l'électeur's post I went and opened up some studies done on the usage of から and came across 原因・理由表現とは which describes the usage of 「から」と「ので」 with 5 usages
> >
> > (1)事態の原因-主節が具体的な事実・事態を表し、従属節が主節の事態そのものを引き起こす原因・理
> >     由を表す場合であ

………　( I would like to copy and end your post here since it it long. )

So, as you had checked out, から denotes the beforementioned reasons.... so on.

Thus, I said NO. Because the conjunctive particle から, as you mentioned, is functioning 
as the conjunctive, thus, it is treated as one sentence with conjunctive から　asserted 
"between".

Oh, I found out it is not so complex. Wow ( just my exclamation, s))